# windows shortcut opening chrome and go to existing tab

Tags: windows, google-chrome, shortcuts

is there a shortcut/combo to open a specific chrome tab directly from windows?
This tab is opened in Chrome in background, I'd like to go to this specific tab by a windows shortcut - possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to open chrome/switch to chrome AND switch to a specific tab with a single hotkey combination then you would need to use something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to combine commands.

However, if you don't mind two commands, you could Alt+Tab to Chrome, then use one of the following Chrome Jump hotkeys:

[Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Ctab-window-shortcuts)

> Jump to a specific tab    Ctrl + 1 through Ctrl + 8
>
> Jump to the rightmost tab Ctrl + 9

Comment: thanks I didn't know the Ctrl+1 ~8 function, it helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! If you could accept my answer (click the check mark) and upvote it it would help me access more privileges here on the site.